Exportar query de una BBDD remota DSN
A ver, llevo atascado con esto ya unas buenas horas. Tengo el driver ODBC instalado y un DSN establecido para una base de datos concreta que está en otro server. A través de excel todo va bien, puedo ver las tablas y su contenido, a través de "Obtener datos externos -> desde otras fuentes". Pongo el usuario, la clave y el nombre del DSN y todo bien.
A través del Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio he creado, con un servidor vinculado, el acceso a la BBDD, y también perfecto. Puedo lanzar queries sin problemas.
El problema viene en que necesito automatizar esto, es decir, necesito que se genere todas las noches un csv con el resultado de una query. Con lo cual, he probado a acceder a los datos de esa BBDD a través de la consola con:
bcp, sqlcmd, osql, y nada, de momento no lo he conseguido.
Comandos como este no me van:
bcp "SELECT * FROM mitabla" queryout mitabla.csv -dAuto02as -Spc-integral\integral -Uadmin -Padmin
SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Error de inicio de sesión del usuario 'admin'.
Pero el usuario y la clave de la BBDD son correctos. Son esos. De hecho, si cambio el parámetro -d y pongo -dasdf, me canta el mismo error, en lugar de decirme BBDD inexistente. Con lo cual, el usuario y la clave que le estoy diciendo no los está introduciendo en la BBDD correcta, por eso no entrará.
ODBC y el DSN: https://ibb.co/zV5cfHV
Servidor vinculado en el SSMS: https://ibb.co/wQxBCqK

as intentando asi ´bcp "SELECT * FROM mitabla" queryout mitabla.csv -c -t, -d Auto02as -S pc-integral\integral -U admin -P admin
´

No funciona. El problema está por otro lado.
